# map.on('click', onClick) is not fired after zoomBox

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) along with [leaflet.wms](https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms) plugin to retrieve some layers from a WMS server and show them to the user. Among other things, the user can click on the map to see information related to a specific region (coordinates that represent that clicked point). 
This is working fine as the following:

- create map
- add map.on('click', onClick) handler
- create layer (L.wms.overlay)
- add layer into the map
- user clicks
- get information from the clicked point (getFeatureInfo)

but when the user zooms in the map by using [zoomBox](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-options), the click event does NOT fire!

Notice that leaflet.wsm plugin only works with leaflet 0.8-dev. So, I'm using this leaflet version.
I saw that in this [demo](http://heigeo.github.io/leaflet.wms/examples/) (from leaflet.wms) this problem also happens. Furthermore, it doesn't happen on 0.7.2 (demo [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start-example.html)) leaflet version. 
Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?